# Why BlockDeviceMapping does not create UUID?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, fdisk, block-device

In Linux machines, block devices have UUID

Below is the CloudFormation template:

```
 "BlockDeviceMappings": [
        {
            "DeviceName" : "/dev/sdf",
            "Ebs" : { 
                    "VolumeSize" : "20",
                    "DeleteOnTermination" : true 
                    }
        }
    ],
```

that creates block device of size 20 GB

but, below command does not show UUID on Amazon Linux instance.

```
$ lsblk -o +UUID --fs /dev/sdf
NAME    FSTYPE LABEL UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT        UUID
nvme2n1 ext4                                              /ecs/app_home
```

---

How to make `"BlockDeviceMappings"` generate UUID for `/dev/sdf`? Idea is to use that UUID and run `mkfs.ext4 -U ${uuid_var}`...